# Are undead immune to the Daze cantrip?

Tags: undead, pathfinder-2e

Daze (CRB p327) has the *mental* and *nonlethal* keyword.

I would assume it does not affect undead, but I found no such keywords in the Bestiary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Daze affects some Undead

There is no blanket immunity for undead to *either* mental nor nonlethal (nor stunned, for that matter).

[Skeletal Giants](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=375) are immune to Mental, so it would not work on them (spitballing, I would guess it's the lack of a brain). I would be wrong, though, because [Wraiths](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=417) (an incorporeal undead) has no immunity to the spell. Its Resistance 5 *would* apply, potentially negating the damage caused.

**In summary**, [Mindless](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=108) undead are not affected by Daze; many others are (although they may be Resistant).

Comment: Of course Wraiths aren't immune, they have a brain after all, it's just that it mostly consists of leftover bits of soul. :p